# best way to implement a UILabel with advanced autolayout and HTML capability?

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, autolayout, nsattributedstring

What is the best way to implement a UILabel with advanced autolayout and HTML capability for iOS7 or above?

I have used a native UILabel with NSAttributedStrings and it works everything except links. Can I add this functionality without adding TTTAttributedText or another weird libraries that complicate my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to initialise your `NSAttributedString` like this: `NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [myHtmlString dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes: &attributes error: nil];`?

Comment: If not for UILabel, this works for UITextView. (By the way `NSDictionary* attributes = nil;` was missing in my last comment)